# Spring Boot 3 + Oauth2 Resource Server : CORS

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, cors

I'm trying to migrate a new Spring boot 2.7.4 application to Spring boot 3(.0.4).

I use the dependency "spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server".

My security config :

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http
.cors()
.configurationSource(request -> {
    var cors = new CorsConfiguration();
    cors.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:8080"));
    cors.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    cors.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
    cors.setAllowCredentials(true);
    return cors;
}).and()
.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
        authorizeRequests
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
)
.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
        oauth2ResourceServer
                .jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter())
)
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    return http.build();
}
```

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jws-algorithms: RS512
          issuer-uri: https://xxxxx.xxxxx.net
          jwk-set-uri: https://xxxxx.xxxxx.net/ext/oauth/JWKS
```

It's working great with Spring boot 2.7.4 and VueJS (Vue 3 + Axios) i have no CORS problems.

But If I switch to spring boot 3.0.4, it doesn't work, i have this error :

[CORS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ChHr.png)

I tried to follow https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide by updating to Spring Security 5.8 first with spring boot and its working but as soon as I switch to spring boot 3, it doesn't work.

does anyone have an idea of the problem? thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Well... The configuration was simply not being used... i don't know why but i need to add @Configuration on my Class who was not needed with Spring Boot 2

from :

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
```

to :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
```